# Using pytest.mark.parametrize to read from list to generate tests dynamically

Tags: pytest

I have a function which reads yaml file and generates test iterations as a list of dictionaries like below:

```py
Iterations = lib_iterations()

print Iterations

Iterations = [{'mode':1,'format':5,'ip':'192.16.1.103'},
            {'mode':2,'format':6,'ip':'192.16.1.104'},
            {'mode':2,'format':8,'ip':'192.16.1.110'},
            {'mode':6,'format':2,'ip':'192.16.1.105'},
            {'mode':5,'format':7,'ip':'192.16.1.102'},
            {'mode':4,'format':2,'ip':'192.16.1.101'}]
```

I need to be able to pass this set to `pytest.mark.parametrize` to generate a test for each iteration/each row in the list.

I do not know the dictionary keys before I call the function `lib_iterations` which generates this list of dictionaries.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 12):

If your problem is how to pass Iterations list to pytest parametrize decorator, then you can do this:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('testdata', [i for i in Iterations])
```

If content of Iterations is unknown in the test module then you can use `pytest_generate_tests` hook. In that hook function you can load the yaml file and pass its content to `metafunc.parametrize`:

```py
import yaml

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'testdata' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        with open("testdata.yml", 'r') as f:
            Iterations = yaml.load(f)
            metafunc.parametrize('testdata', [i for i in Iterations])
```

The test function using this fixture:

```py
def test_it(testdata):
    print testdata
```